# Initialize C++ class member with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, initializer

I'm trying to initialize templated class member with a lambda, via the
constructor, like this.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class lambda_template_class {
public:
    lambda_template_class(std::function<T(T)>& f) { }
};

class test {
protected:
    lambda_template_class<int> member{ [] (int x) { return x; } };
};

int main() {
    test t;
}
```

But it does not seem to accept any syntax. Is there a simple way to make this work?

Comment: `lambda_template_class(std::function<T(T)>& f)` -> `lambda_template_class(std::function<T(T)> f)`

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem.

Comment: Just a note, your question can reproduced simpler as `void foo(int&){} foo(5);`, it has nothing to do with functions or lambdas. It's just the problem of passing a temporary by reference (and I do hope you don't have any member variables as references, it won't work).

Comment: I can't mark comments as solution, but you did solve the problem. Can you post an answer which I can mark as a solution?